# Finding nested array data with elemMatch in MongoDB/Meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

collection structure as such:

```
{"_id" : "abc",
"potentialUsers" : [{"userID" : "def"}, 
                    {"userID" : "ghi"}]
},

{"_id" : "123",
"potentialUsers" : [{"userID" : "456"}, 
                    {"userID" : "789"}]
},
```

I want to query if user abc has the user def in their potential users array. My current query (client) is

```
    getPendingLiftRequests: function() {
        return collection.find({}, {potentialUsers: {$elemMatch: {userID: Meteor.user().services.facebook.id}}});
    }
```

On the server I publish all of that collection to the user, and then just selectively show it based on the view of the client. However, when I try to use an elemMatch on the array, it just shows all of the records, when it should only show 1.

Comment: I don't know meteor, but that `{}` as first argument in a mongo  `find` looks pretty suspicious. It looks like an empty query which returns all documents. What is the first argument supposed to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `$elemMatch` here. This should work:

```
var fId = Meteor.user().services.facebook.id;
return collection.find({'potentialUsers.userID': fid});
```

Answer (score 2):

Have look at the documentation for minimongo in Meteor:
http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find

You have to use the fields option to get the desired result.

```
getPendingLiftRequests: function() {
    return collection.find({}, { fields: { potentialUsers: {$elemMatch: {userID: Meteor.user().services.facebook.id}}}});
}
```